# renaming a file before uploading to digital ocean spaces using laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, flysystem, laravel-storage

To upload a file I use

`Storage::disk('spaces')->putFile('uploads', $request->file, 'public');`

The file is saved successfully on digital ocean spaces. But I want to rename it to something like this `user_1_some_random_string.jpg`. And then save it.

How can I do it?

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: I will let you know very soon.. havent tried it yet. Im outside

Answer (score 0):

The `move` method may be used to **rename** or **move** an existing file to a new location:
`Storage::move('hodor/oldfile-name.jpg', 'hodor/newfile-name.jpg');`

Also:
If you would not like a file name to be automatically assigned to your stored file, you may use the storeAs method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments:

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
    'avatars', $request->user()->id
);
```

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem

Answer (score 0):

try use rand()

```
$ext  = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$name = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$ext;
Storage::disk('spaces')->putFile('uploads', $name, 'public');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but I found an answer for anyone still looking.

You need to use the method putFileAs, as far as I can see

1. the first parameter is the bucket/location. I tested this and it will create a new folder if you use 'uploads/testz' it created the 'testz' in the uploads folder on spaces.
2. the second parameter is the request file object, in my case $request->file('file')
3. the third parameter is the filename that you WANT to store the file as. I tested and if you 'testz/<yourspecialfilename.extension>' it will create the same folder as in parameter 1, which suggests to me that the method concats param 1 and 3.
   So the full snippet in my controller is

   ```
    public function create(Request $request){ Storage::disk('spaces')->putFileAs('uploads/testz', $request->file('file'), 'mychosenfilename.mydesiredextension');
    return redirect()->back();}
   ```